# Scapy - Raw layer to string and into a wx.TextCtrl

Tags: unicode, wxpython, python-2.6, scapy

I'm using scapy to show all layers of a packet and when the packet has a UDP layer and Raw it sometimes gives me an 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte...' and I dont know what to do .. help?
this is the line of code that makes trouble :

```
 self.txt.SetValue(str(pkt.getlayer(Raw).load))
```

I need a way to show the Raw data in the TextCtrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the data as unicode instead of a string:

```
self.txt.SetValue(u'%s' % (pkt.getlayer(Raw).load))
```

I wouldn't be too surprised if this didn't work though, so be sure to read up on how to use unicode in Python:

- https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

You should also check out the following articles:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/UnicodeBuild
- http://kevino.theolliviers.com/python-unicode.html
- http://zetcode.com/wxpython/in18/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Internationalization

If all else fails, you can always try converting the unicode to ascii using this fun package:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode

Comment: What does 'pkt.getlayer(Raw).load' return?  What type and maybe some sample data would be interesting.